# RestClient bug on response redirect encoding

Tags: ruby, encoding, uri, rest-client

When trying to get this page:

```
resp = RestClient.get("http://www.radios.com.br/aovivo/XXXX/24924")
```

I get this error:

```
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://www.radios.com.br/aovivo/Radio-Gospel-Ajduk?s/24924
    from /Users/danicuki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:176:in `split'
    from /Users/danicuki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:211:in `parse'
```

I think this is happening because the response redirect url has encoding problem. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Non-ASCII characters in URIs must be urlencoded:

```
url = "http://www.radios.com.br/aovivo/XXXX/24924"
resp = RestClient.get(URI::encode(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply patch for RestClient: (in version `2.1.0` it is not fixed yet)

```
RestClient::AbstractResponse.module_eval do

  alias _origin_follow_redirection _follow_redirection
  def _follow_redirection(new_args, &block)
    # cannot follow redirection if there is no location header
    raise exception_with_response unless headers[:location]

    # Fix URI::InvalidURIError: URI must be ascii only
    headers[:location] = URI::encode headers[:location]

    _origin_follow_redirection new_args, &block
  end

end
```